# UITableView won't display headerView.xib

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Am trying to get a UITableView to display a headerView.xib which I have created, but after building it, nothing shows. Want to make the UITableView editable, and have added three methods to the ItemsViewController.m file, but nothing shows.

What's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here are the relevant files:

ItemsViewController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ItemsViewController : UITableViewController
{
  IBOutlet UIView *headerView;
}

-(UIView *)headerView;
-(IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)toggleEditingMode:(id)sender;

@end
```

ItemsViewController.m

```
#import "ItemsViewController.h"
#import "BNRItemStore.h"
#import "BNRItem.h"

@implementation ItemsViewController // Incomplete implementation

-(id)init
{
  // Call the superclass's designated initializer
  self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
  if (self) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      [[BNRItemStore sharedStore]createItem];
    }

  }
  return self;
}

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
  return [self init];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore]allItems]count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


  // Check for a reusable cell first, use that if it exists
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

  // If there is no reusable cell of this type, create a new one
  if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
  } 

  // Set the text on the cell with the description of the item
  // that is at the nth index of items, where n = row this cell
  // will appear in on the tableview
  BNRItem *p = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore]allItems]objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

  [[cell textLabel]setText:[p description]];

  return cell;
}

-(UIView *)headerView
{
  // If we haven't loaded the headerView yet
  if (!headerView) {
    //Load HeaderView.xib
    [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil];
  }
  return headerView;
}

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sec
{
  return [self headerView];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tv heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)sec
{
  // The height of the header view should be determined from the height of the 
  // view in the XIB file
  return [[self headerView]bounds].size.height;
}



@end
```

Comment: In the header's xib, is a connection made between the header view and File's Owner? File's Owner should also have its class set in IB to ItemsViewController.

Comment: Yes, that was my problem. Now it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One or both of the following things is not set up correctly. First, the File's Owner object in HeaderView.xib needs to have its class set to `ItemsViewController`. After that, the `headerView` outlet needs to be connected from File's Owner to the top-level view in the xib.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and resolved it by changing the line of code under the comment  //Load HeaderView.xib to

```
// Load HeaderView.xib
    headerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
```

the nib file only has one view so I assign it the last(only) view.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems significant that the `loadNibNamed` method inside of your `headerView` method returns an array of the contents of the nib file, yet you've done nothing with those contents. Maybe you should find the view inside of the unarchived objects and set your `headerView` to the corresponding view from inside of the nib file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss implement these method ? I'm not sure these class already set default section value = 1.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```